# Make / Build with geany

Tags: c, build, geany

I have problem on build.
My error is something like that:  "test.c" error:  test.h   error"

I have on source code:

```
#include <test.h>
```

How to add this on build?
To be spesific How to link this library? Can i link it through Geany?
Operating System ubuntu +  Geany as compile

Comment: Um.. What Geany are you talking? I know one,and this it is a text editor.

Comment: Geany 0.21.  I saw that i can compile through geany! Its a simple editor

Comment: Have sure that you compiler can see the path of test.h file? maybe you need to specific it,e.g by using `-I` in the gcc and gcc-like compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these simple steps:

- Create a directory and place your `test.c` and `test.h` in the same directory.
- In C source file you should write:

`#include "test.h"` which will search for the header file in current directory as well as the include library path, instead of, the `#include <test.h>` which will search for test.h in include libraries path only.

- Build as usual, using geany.